# Clustering geospatial data in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have several tables that contain geospatial information including latitude and longitude.  The volume of data is way too much to display individually as the maps just hang, so I was wondering what kind of grouping/clustering strategies have been implemented by folks in the oracle world.

I have grouped on truncated values with success, but that yields a grid like pattern.

I'm looking for something that 'snaps' locations together that are nearest to one another.

Answer (score 0):

try import that data into Oracle as an SDO_GEOMETRY, which will allow you to perform spatial analysis and visualize the data using a range of tools. To bring your lat/long's over as geometries, format your lat/long's into WKT and use the SDO_GEOMETRY constructor.

For example

```
Lat               Lon                 WKT                                       SDO_GEOMETRY
-------------     ----------------    -------------------------------------     -----------------------------------------------------------
59.4564555909     -135.3133542922     POINT (-135.3133542922 59.4564555909)     SDO_GEOMETRY('POINT (-135.3133542922 59.4564555909)', 8307)
64.841125         -148.01808          POINT (-148.01808 64.841125)              SDO_GEOMETRY('POINT (-148.01808 64.841125)', 8307)
```